# How to prevent Multi-Value field showing duplicates in Access 365 2016

Tags: ms-access, field, multivalue

Im using Microsoft Access 365 2016.

I have created a multi-value field in a table so that i can choose multiple values from a list of check box options (similar to the drop down menu in a field table).

When I click the drop down arrow It shows all the values from the lookup table and displays duplicate options like this:

Null,

Yes,

Yes,

No,

NuLL,

Null,

No

How can I get it to display only unique options like this:

Null,

Yes,

No

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make `Unique Values=Yes` on property sheet of your .

[image]

When you selecting values from other table as ***Multiselect Combobox*** `Row Source` then build a query from table and make `Unique Values` to `Yes`.